# Cannot import LSHForest from sklearn in Google colab

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

While importing the library `LSHForest` in Google colab, it is coming out as `ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHForest' from 'sklearn.neighbors' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/__init__.py)`.

I took the code from the official documentation [Link](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LSHForest.html)

The code is:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import LSHForest
```

Comment: As per the following github issue , probably it has been removed, and not being added anymore due to less support https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

`LSHForest()` has been dead for years. You'll have to either downgrade your sklearn version or, preferably, just use `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors()`.